# JSON string that contains double quotes for a value is being sent to the controller as NULL

Tags: ajax

I make this AJAX call:

```
function CreateProjectTree(sc)
{
    debugger;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../api/projects/SearchProjects",
        data: sc,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json"
    }).done(function(data)
    {
        buildTree(data);
    }).fail(function(jqXHR, status, error)
    {
        console.log("Error: " + error);
    });
}
```

If the variable `sc` does not have any double quotes for any of the values, (e.g. `"Person": "Jack"`), it works fine.

However, if the object contains double quotes as such: `"Person": ""Jack""`, it'll send the object as NULL to the controller.

I'm not sure why this is happening.

Do I have to do anything special in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`"Person": ""Jack""` doesn't work because the second quote on `""Jack""` is an end quote (two quotation marks make a string: ""). The JSON is bad because of this, and is therefore being treated as `null`. You can fix it by either one of two methods:

1) Change from using `"` to `'` in your JSON: `'Person': '"Jack"'`

2) Use an escape to use a quote inside a quote: `"Person": "\"Jack\""`